# How to embed particular version of python interpreter in c in OS X

Tags: python, c, macos

I want to embed python in C. But I find that the version of python interpreter which is embedded in my program is 2.7 (The default version on mac).

How could I specify particular version of python interpreter when I compile the c codes in mac os x. The gcc in os x is definitely different from in linux.

I have already installed python3 through HomeBrew.

Thanks a lot.

---

UPDATE: 
I try to use `python3.4-config --cflags` and `python3.4-config --ldflags` to find out the required compiler and linker flags. Then I get these recommended flags when compiling & linking:

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m -Wno-unused-result -Werror=declaration-after-statement -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include
```

and

```
-L/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m -ldl -framework CoreFoundation -lpython3.4m
```

After this, I assemble these flags along with source file into gcc, and obtain an error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyUnicodeUCS2_FromString", referenced from:
      _main in py2-5d8da5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The C code which I test here comes from [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/extending/embedding.html#pure-embedding)

Comment: You'll want to specify custom linker and compiler flags. e.g: ``-L and -I`` to the Python3 installation you have.

Comment: Could show me an example? I am new in python.

Comment: Only if you show how you are compilng your source now.

Comment: I use `gcc source.c -framework Python` command. I have tried `gcc source.c -framework Python3` but failed.

Comment: Unless you built Python3 as a framework, you'll want to use `gcc -L/path/to/python3/lib -I/path/to/python3/include -lpython source.c`

Comment: I have updated my question. I used compiler flags to specify directories of python3 libs and headers. When compiling, everything is ok but a linking error reported: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_PyUnicodeUCS2_FromString", referenced from:`

Comment: A simple Google search for `_PyUnicodeUCS2_FromString` shows that this linking problem is far from unknown.  Judging from the file name `py2-5d8da5.o`, maybe the C code you are compiling requires Python 2 and does not work with Python 3.  Or you could look at the Google search results to track down the problem formally.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same errors when trying to do this tutorial on OSX. You don't need all of the flags that the config utility spits out. You definitely don't need the corefoundation framework if you're just doing the embedding tutorial. Just use the include directory for headers:

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m
```

, and the library to link to:

```
-L/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m -lpython3.4m
```

so here's a one-liner to compile and link:

```
gcc -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m -L/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m -lpython3.4m /path/to/main.c -o /path/to/output/executable
```